# Windows IIS Permissions for Prestashop

Tags: php, iis, permissions, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

Hi i am installing a prestashop framework on an IIS and as you may know it asks for some directories to be accessible for writing. 
I gave the permissions as needed and continued to install but due to further modules and themes installations i got errors due to not enough permissions.
I reversed every thing and on the second try i gave IUSR full control on the parent directory of prestashop to not have anymore problems.
Note this is a test version for now.

Q1: Is it ok to leave IUSR with full control permissions or will it be vulnerable? 
Note also that the site will be secured.

The other idea i have is, giving full control until complete installation than leave with write access only those directories that prestashop writes to such as ~/cache etc...

Q2: Will directories with write access on IUSR be vulnerable for, for example code injection?

Thanks

Comment: According to me the second one is correct `The other idea i have is, giving full control until complete installation than leave with write access only those directories that prestashop writes to such as ~/cache etc...`

Q2: Will directories with write access on IUSR be vulnerable for, for example code injection?  No (is there any case that someone else have your details? if no then totally cool)

Comment: What do you mean by details? Web server credentials?

Comment: yes exactly.BTW i am not a prestashop master

Comment: No no one will have credentials of the server. Thanks for your help though